# Increment score in Sprite Kit to show in HUD

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I know I'm close in getting the getting the score to increment in my game.

When I explicitly change the code to add a integer (5 for example) instead of "%d", the score shows in the HUD when a coin is touched :

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
}
```

to:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    lblScore.text = String(format: "5", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
}
```

[image]

However if I leave the "%d", then nothing happens. I'm not sure how to increment the score in the HUD or where to make changes.

Here's the rest of the code.

GameScene.swift:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {

  static let None: UInt32              = 0
  static let Player: UInt32            = 0b1     
  static let CoinNormal: UInt32        = 0b1000  
  static let CoinSpecial: UInt32       = 0b10000  
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

 // HUD 
 var hudNode: SKNode!
 var lblScore: SKLabelNode!
 var lblCoins: SKLabelNode!

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

   // HUD
   hudNode = SKNode()
   hudNode.zPosition = 1000
   cameraNode.addChild(hudNode)


   // Coins
   // 1
   let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "powerup05_1")
   coin.position = convertPoint(CGPoint(x: 300, y: self.size.height-100), toNode: cameraNode)
   coin.zPosition = 1000
   hudNode.addChild(coin)

   // 2
   lblCoins = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
   lblCoins.fontSize = 70
   lblCoins.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
   lblCoins.position = convertPoint(CGPoint(x: 375, y: self.size.height-100), toNode: cameraNode)
   lblCoins.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
   lblCoins.zPosition = 1000

   // 3
   lblCoins.text = String(format: "X %d", GameState.sharedInstance.coins)
   hudNode.addChild(lblCoins)

   // Score
   // 4
   lblScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
   lblScore.fontSize = 70
   lblScore.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
   lblScore.position = convertPoint(CGPoint(x: self.size.width-325, y: self.size.height-100), toNode: cameraNode)
   lblScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Right
   lblScore.zPosition = 1000

   // 5
   lblScore.text = "0"
   hudNode.addChild(lblScore)
  }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

  lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
}
```

GameState.swift:

```
class GameState {
  var score: Int
  var highScore: Int
  var coins: Int

  init() {
    // Init
    score = 0
    highScore = 0
    coins = 0

    // Load game state
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    highScore = defaults.integerForKey("highScore")
    coins = defaults.integerForKey("coins")
  }

  func saveState() {
    // Update highScore if the current score is greater
    highScore = max(score, highScore)

    score = max(score, highScore)

    // Store in user defaults
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
    defaults.setInteger(coins, forKey: "coins")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  }

  class var sharedInstance: GameState {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = GameState()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
  }
}
```

Comment: @James Zaghini Thanks for fixing the format. I must have missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to increment the score by this line:

`GameState.sharedInstance.score += 1`

Or replace 1 with another number by how many points you want to increment.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using `GameState.sharedInstance.score` to store a score. But you never update it. You have to increment the score each time when player scores. This part:

```
 lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.score)
```

only reads from a score variable.

Also this part doesn't make sense:

```
highScore = max(score, highScore)

score = max(score, highScore)  //remove this
```

score variable is not the same as highscore variable.

Comment: So, how do I increment the score? I'm assuming it's in the `func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)` method? How would I write it? Thanks

Comment: @Paul Like any other variable GameState.sharedInstance.score! += 1 (or any number of points you want). When to increment the score depends on your game logic.

Comment: That was it! I knew I needed to increment, but didn't know how to write it in Swift. Now I need to figure out how to add different points for special coins. Add that answer to your official answer and I'll award you.

Comment: @Paul I believe he answered your question. If you have a different question you should create a new question.

Comment: @SkylerLauren Yup! But the answer is in the comments. He just needs to move `GameState.sharedInstance.score += 1` to the official answer area. I don't have a new question yet.

Comment: @Whirlwind Please add the correct answer to your answer and I will award you with the  correct answer.